# How to do integer factorial compute by recursion using increasively number?

Tags: c, recursion, factorial

Here is the decreasing solution for factorial recursion :

```c
int fact(int n)
{
     if (n == 0 || n == 1){
          return 1;
     } else {
          return n * fact(n - 1);
     }
}
```

If I want to do factorial recursion by increasing instead of decreasing :

```c
int fact(int n, int i)
{
     if (n == 0 || n == 1){
          return 1;
     } else {
          if (i+1 <= n) {
               return n * fact(n, i + 1);
          }
          return n;
     }
}
```

It returned `15625` when I called `fact(5, 0)`

Thanks in advance

Comment: `15625 = power(5,5+(0+1))`, does that ring a bell? :-)

Comment: @SupportUkraine I know, I'm just want to understand the logic of Recursion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int fact(int n, int i)
{
     if (n == 0 || n == 1){
          return 1;
     } else {
          if (i+1 <= n) {
               return n * fact(n, i + 1);
          }
          return n;
     }
}
```

In above function, you are calculating `n^{n}` instead of `n!` due to `return n * fact(n, i+1)` statement.

Below recursion function(with minimum changes from the original function that OP posted) will work if we call it as `fact(n, 0)`

```
int fact(int n, int i)
{
     if (n == 0 || n == 1){
          return 1;
     } else {
          if (i+1 < n) {
               return (i+1) * fact(n, i + 1);
          }
          return n;
     }
}
```